# Send post request using OkHttpClient

Tags: java, android, post, http-post, okhttp

I have an activity with 2 EditText.
When the user is clicking on the Send button, I want to send EditText value to my  server.
i tried to make a POST request when the user clicking on the button.
The problem is when the user is clicking on the button  He  get a error, and the application closing automatically.
This is my code:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import okhttp3.FormBody;
    import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
    import okhttp3.Request;
    import okhttp3.RequestBody;

    public class register extends AppCompatActivity {
        private EditText nameE,l_nameE;
        private Button registerE;
        private String name,l_name,token;
        boolean thread_running = true;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
            token =  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Toast.makeText(this, token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final Button register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
             nameE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
             l_nameE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);


            register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    registerToken();
                }
            });
        }
        public void intialize(){
            name = nameE.getText().toString().trim();
            l_name = l_nameE.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        public boolean validate(){
            boolean e=true;
            if(name.equals("")){
                e=false;
                nameE.setError("enter name");
            }else if(l_name.equals("")){
                e=false;
                l_nameE.setError("enter l_name");
            }
            return e;
        }
        private void registerToken() {
            intialize();
            if (!validate()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "err", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
              reg();
            }
        }
        public void reg(){
            Toast.makeText(this, "reg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
.add("name",name)
.add("l_name",l_name)
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://192.168.0.106/fcm/register.php")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();

            try {
                client.newCall(request).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

thank you

Comment: Check you are passing token as string not in JSONObject. Check you have make API is string request or JSONObjectRequest.

Comment: What's the error? Please attach a stack trace.

Comment: The application is stopped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a network call on the main thread. That is not allowed on Android as it will block your whole application until the request is completed.
A solution will be to wrap your network call in an AsyncTask for example.

But as you are using OKHttpClient, they are offering an async api for such things.

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override 
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        //something went wrong
        Log.e(YOUR_TAG, e);
    }
    @Override 
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws    IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Response not sueccessful   " + response);
        }
        //success do whatever you want. for example -->
        Log.d(YOUR_TAG, response.body().string());
    }
}
```

So in your example instead of an synchronous call like

```
client.newCall(request).execute();
```

you have to use the async callback version like shown above.

hopefully that helps

Edit: For more recipes take a look at the wiki page: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: How can I change the post request to UTF-8?

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to set the MediaType for the request. Just take a look at the wiki link.